# How do I get a user name from the Firstore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrsZ1.png)I'd like to import my user name into FireStore, but I can't import it How do I get it? When you take a log, the log gets a good value, but when you build an app, you only get an email and your user name is not available. Why doing this?
`AccountFragment.kt`

```
class AccountFragment : Fragment() {

    var user : FirebaseUser? = null
    var firestore: FirebaseFirestore? = null
    var fragmentView: View? = null


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_fragment, container, false)

        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser



        return fragmentView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        val docRef = firestore!!.collection ( "user" ). document (user!!.uid)
        val source = Source.CACHE

        docRef.get(source).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                val document = task.result
                user_email.text = user?.email
                user_name.text = UserModel().userName
            }else{

            }
        }
  }
```

`UserModel.kt`

```
class UserModel {
    var userEmail: String? = null
    var userName: String? = null
    var uid: String? = null
    var password: String? = null
    var timestamp: Long? = null
    var content: String? = null
    var profileImageUrl: String? = null
    var pushToken: String? = null
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the document you stored under `/user/$uid`?

Comment: Please add what Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also responde with @.

Comment: ok im add document screenshot